# Join two similar queries made to the same table in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

Good evening, I have generated two queries to a PostgreSQL database, which are the following:

```
SELECT tarea, count(estado) AS "TotalCompletos" from tabla WHERE estado = 'Completo' GROUP BY  tarea;
```

[Query_1_result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91YV2.png)

```
SELECT tarea, count(estado) AS "TotalIncompletos" from tabla WHERE estado = 'Incompleto' GROUP BY  tarea;
```

[Query_2_result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu1Zn.png)

My question is, how can I merge the above two queries into one query in order to produce a result similar to the following?

[Expected_result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFJgC.png)

I have used `UNION` but I do not get the expected results. Attached is some sample code from the database I am using: [Demo_DB](https://rextester.com/FKIF46133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with q1 as (
SELECT tarea, count(estado) AS "TotalCompletos" from tabla WHERE estado = 'Completo' GROUP BY  tarea
),
q2 as (
SELECT tarea, count(estado) AS "TotalIncompletos" from tabla WHERE estado = 'Incompleto' GROUP BY  tarea
)
select tarea, coalesce("TotalCompletos", 0) as "TotalCompletos", coalesce("TotalIncompletos", 0) as "TotalIncompletos"
from q1 full join q2 using (tarea);
```